# Crystal Reports integration with Hadoop/Hive/HPLSQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, crystal-reports, integration, hive-hplsql

We are migrating data from Oracle to Hadoop and there is a requirement 
 to continue  use the existing reporting tool(Crystal Report) to generate reports from Hadoop (instead of Oracle)

In the current scenario we are using an Oracle Stored PROC to do few aggregations /logic.
Now with the above requirement and migrated data, The Options that we considered are

1. Use `HPLSQL` (instead of Oracle `PLSQL`) and call it from Crystal Reports.However it appears that there are challenges with this approach because unlike Oracle Stored Procs, 
   `HPLSQL` Stored Procs are not registered in the DB catalouge and hence Crystal reports may  be unable to find / access those `HPLSQL` STored PROCS.
2. Create the custom aggregation /logic in java and expose it as a webservice  which can be invoked /consumed from Crystal Reports

The help/guidance needed here is to find out whether

a) Did someone successfully called `HPLSQL` Stored Procs form an external tool/ reports like Crystal over `ODBC/JDBC`. If yes, can you share the details?

b) Is there  a better option other than the above mentioned two options to  achieve the requirement?

c) Are there any challenges in using webservices to fetch data and run reports

Thanks in advance and any help is really appreciated.